# Netty Deployment Process

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netty

Can i ask the reason why i cant deploy netty 3.6.1.final on Eclipse
And the Version i download is `netty-3.6.1.Final-dist.tar.bz2`

As i have follow this in pom.xml in dependencies tab and i cant resolve the error

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.1.Final-dist</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The step i follow is https://netty.io/Main/Downloads

Comment: All my File like can resolve..after i make the changes

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

The file is supposed to be downloaded from maven website, not netty.io, don't put `-dist` in your version.

This works for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And then you Run As pom.xml in Eclipse using Maven plugin.

Comment: Hi Nikolay Kuznetsov,
I still unable to compile as my scr folder still having error.
I try with clean build and the error still exist

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the dependency as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

As suggested by Nikolay.

Then go to the project root and run from the command line: `mvn compile`. That should download your dependency. Then refresh eclipse project and you should be good.

Otherwise, please provide more specific information about the error.